# curl works fine in command line, but not in php

Tags: php, curl

I use curl to retrieve the contents of a url from within PHP. It works fine for most url's, but for some, it only returns an empty string ("curl"ing such url's from command line works just fine).
Here's how I run curl:

```
$curl_session = curl_init($site->url);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, TIMEOUT);
$output = curl_exec($curl_session);
curl_close($curl_session);
```

I also checked and curl doesn't seem to give any errors.

Comment: Have you confirmed `$site->url` has a valid value?

Comment: are you sure it's an empty string and not boolean false? `if ($output === FALSE) { die(curl_error($curl_session)); }`

Comment: Yes, John, I even replaced it with the literal value of the url, and it still won't work.

Comment: `$output` has the value `string(0) ""`

Comment: is it possible to know the value of `$site->url` in order to do some testing?

Comment: Try adding `curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,TRUE);` to the script to debug why its not working

Comment: @user1814543 Can you give an example of a URL where this works from the command line but not in PHP and also provide the command line command you are using?

Comment: Same issue here. The 'output' for me says: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to <ip-address>: Permission denied`. Works perfectly fine when using curl on commandline. (my php script actually runs another shell script with then runs curl from within).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
echo shell_exec("www.example.com");
```